# Database connection error with Visual studio

Tags: mysql

[help me emergency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtAtr.png)

Hello,
I have websites in asp.net and i am trying to connect the database on my site using visual studio 2010. or 2012 both.

Help me to connect the database properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this link it may help you:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165037(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzedkwye%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Hello #Anju,
i have read your link through given the link.
but i don't found it helpful for my error.
hope to see ur comments.